# Batch file %%i was unexpected at this time

Tags: variables, batch-file

I am trying to get a patch file to set a variable to the number of instances that are running for a particular executable but am getting this error:

```
%%i was unexpected at this time
```

Here is my code:

```
   for /f %%i in ('wmic process where name="chrome.exe" ^| find "chrome.exe" /c') do set var=%%i
```

I looked for an answer but none of the suggestions worked, even escaping the | with a ^.

Comment: I think `find /c` gives you a single number, so there shouldn't be any looping involved.

Comment: have you executed this directly in command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing this directly in command prompt try this:

```
for /f %i in ('wmic process where "name='chrome.exe'" get caption /format:value ^| find "chrome.exe" /c') do set var=%i
```

for batch file left the double `%`

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me crazy. I also didn't realize the % had to be different for batch vs cmd.